# Renaming Column Headers

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to map the FactorName in the dataframe FName to the column header names of Stack. Ie Factor1 in Stack is actually named Value, Factor 2 is Leverage etc. I have a large dataset so manually renaming is not an option.

```
Stack <- data.frame(rowid=1:3, Factor1=2:4, Factor2=3:5, Factor3=4:6)
FName <- data.frame(FactorID=c("Factor1","Factor2","Factor3"), FactorName=c("Value","Leverage","Growth"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this using `match`:

```
Stack <- data.frame(rowid=1:3, Factor1=2:4, Factor2=3:5, Factor3=4:6)
FName <- data.frame(
    FactorID=c("Factor1","Factor2","Factor3"), 
    FactorName=c("Value","Leverage","Growth")) 

# Matching entries from FName
colnames(Stack) <- ifelse(
    !is.na(FName$FactorName[match(colnames(Stack), FName$FactorID)]),
    as.character(FName$FactorName[match(colnames(Stack), FName$FactorID)]),
    colnames(Stack));

Stack;
# rowid Value Leverage Growth
#1     1     2        3      4
#2     2     3        4      5
#3     3     4        5      6
```

Explanation: We match column names of `Stack` and entries from `FName$FactorID`. If there is a match, replace with `FName$FactorName`, else keep the original column name.

Answer (score 0):

if we have factor names handy then we can use that to change the column names

```
colnames(Stack) <- "facotor header file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `match`, but using indexing instead of `ifelse`

```
# Get indices of matches
m <- match(names(Stack), FName$FactorID)

# replace names where a match is found.
names(Stack)[!is.na(m)] <- as.character(FName$FactorName[m[!is.na(m)]])
```